# File sizes from server and app aren't matching?

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a picture uploading app that I want to make sure a user uploads the image without a partial (corrupt) image if it crashes or they close while it's uploading.

My First thought was to check the file sizes on the server to see if the file size match. Here's my OBJECTIVE-C code:

```
NSString *jpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",sqlImageUploadPathTwo];
NSString *yourPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:jpgPath];
NSFileManager *man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error: NULL];
int result = [attrs fileSize];
NSLog(@"Initial size: %d", result);
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
$file_size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
```

After logging them, I see they appear to be different numbers (but they are somewhat close). I got 337534 from the iPhone app and 349632 from the server.

Why aren't these numbers matching? What would be my best other alternative be?

Thanks!
Coulton

**EDIT:**

Here's some code for my upload:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:jpgPathTwo];
NSLog(@"tempImage: %@", tempImage);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 90);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myflashpics.com/iphone_processes/upload.php?album=%@&id=%@&caption=%@&orient=%@",getAlbumID,theUserID,theCaption,getOrientation];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And here's some PHP:

```
// Start Uploading...
$uploadDir = "./../users/$get_username/pictures/";
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$newName = $uploadDir . $new_id . $uploadFile;
$file_size = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
// Some code to process and make MYSQL queries
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a table of some successful image uploads:

```
Size on app - Size on server
337534      - 349632
390995      - 396789
171797      - 176577
171042      - 179143
```

Sorry, it was uploading the same image. Just updated the results.

**Edit 3:**

PHP code to do MD5 HASH:

```
// I've tried this:
md5("$tmp_location");
// And this:
md5_file("$tmp_location");
```

iPhone app code:

```
CFStringRef md5hash = FileMD5HashCreateWithPath((CFStringRef)yourPath, FileHashDefaultChunkSizeForReadingData);
NSLog(@"MD5 hash of file at path \"%@\": %@", yourPath, (NSString *)md5hash);
CFRelease(md5hash);

(using this: http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/)
```

Comment: `349632` is perfectly divisible by 8. I'm going to wager that the filesize you're getting from the server is the "size on disk" rather than "size of file". Can you post the sizes returned by a few different files?

Comment: @phpnerd211: Strange filesizes.

Comment: Just checked and it was uploading the same image! Weird. Updated with some new results... Thanks!

Comment: @phpnerd211: Try downloading the images from the server and check their filesize, see if they're garbled, check for EXIF data, etc.

Comment: @jnpcl: It's a totally different number... `176863` Weird... Also took a look at the EXIF and it seems to look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: new answer**

I suppose the file sizes are different because simply upload different data.

You do *not* upload the file as it is saved:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:jpgPathTwo];
NSLog(@"tempImage: %@", tempImage);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 90);
```

`imageData` is not guaranteed to be the same as on disk.

Why not using the data from disk directly? Use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];` instead.

**Old answer considering encoding**

It seems like your encoding is wrong - this typically gives slightly mismatching data.

I haven't tried it, but would suggest using `binary` instead of `application/octet-stream`. If this doesn't fix the problem, maybe the server side part of saving gets it wrong.

Comment: Tried changing it to binary, however the MD5 hashes and file sizes still don't match.

Comment: You aren't uploading the file as on disk. ;-) Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. It matches now! You have no idea how long I was staring at this.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is MD5 hash. It is probably the best alternative.

How do you upload the images? Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Just posted some. If they are different numbers, wouldn't the MD5 be different?

Comment: @phpnerd211: You could MD5 the contents of the file, not the filesize.

Comment: I am familiar with using MD5 with text strings in PHP like: md5("stuff here"). How exactly would you do it with a JPEG file in objective-c? Thanks!

Comment: Check out this site: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17659-calculating-md5-hash-large-file.html You can use any C-implementation of MD5-hashing since Obj-C is a superclass of C, so feel free to seek one which you like :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. However, the hashes don't match: `1150edcf59505a544c6400e912c83dd1` (from phone) & `7417aab16d34689082e4966441154d97` (from server). I'll post the code in my question above.